# String equals vs. byte array comparsion

Tags: java

Are byte array comparisons (using a simple loop to check each index) faster than using `String.equals(Object)`? I don't think so, but some people seem to prefer byte-based operations instead of String-based operations including byte array equality-checks.

On a side node, when does it make sense to use byte-arrays instead of Strings? Do you think for example implementing the Levenshtein-algorithm to compute a metric for the "distance" of two Strings. Do you think it speeds up the computation if it's based on bytes instead of Strings/Chars? I don't think so, but maybe.

For instance if it's used to encode Tokens as in https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/src/main/java/org/basex/util/Token.java

Comment: If I remember correctly, a String and a byte array are two separate things, and characters are UCS-2 or UTF-16 or something.  If so, you're asking whether toasters are faster than food processors.

Comment: @David your analogy is a bit off, in my opinion. There's nothing special about Java `char`s. They're just unsigned 16 bit integers, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: They are still different from bytes.

Answer (score 9):

Strings don't contain bytes. They contain chars. And the String equals obviously compares the chars of the two strings (unless they don't even have the same length). Since String has a direct access to the underlying char array, which external code doesn't have, it's obviously faster to use `equals`.

It makes sense to use byte arrays when dealing with binary data (binary streams, cryptography, etc.). When dealing with textual data, using Strings, StringBuilders, CharSequence or char arrays is better. It all depends on the situation.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not the same, I'm wondering if it makes sense if you convert for instance tokens as in https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/src/main/java/org/basex/util/Token.java

Comment: Why copying the entire Strings into byte arrays just to compare them? It just doesn't make sense. Strings must be transformed into bytes when written to a stream (file, socket, etc.). And the IO Writers are written for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JMH** for such benchmarks. Below is a example for your question

```
@BenchmarkMode({ Mode.AverageTime, Mode.Throughput })
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 3, time = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 10)
@Threads(1)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class StringVsBytesComparison {

    String s1 = "Hello";
    String s2 = "Hello";

    @Benchmark
    public boolean stringComparison() {
        String s1 = "Hello";
        String s2 = "Hello";

        return s1.equals(s2);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean bytesComparison() {
        byte[] ba1 = s1.getBytes();
        byte[] ba2 = s2.getBytes();

        return Arrays.equals(ba1, ba2);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Benchmark                                  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error   Units
StringVsBytesComparison.bytesComparison   thrpt    5   0.011 ± 0.001  ops/ns
StringVsBytesComparison.stringComparison  thrpt    5   0.466 ± 0.010  ops/ns
StringVsBytesComparison.bytesComparison    avgt    5  90.547 ± 3.312   ns/op
StringVsBytesComparison.stringComparison   avgt    5   2.166 ± 0.062   ns/op
```

**Clearly string comparison wins.**
Please find the entire source code [here](https://github.com/ashishb888/java-poc/tree/master/java-jmh)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small test to see, rather than guessing:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class StringComparisons {

    static String[] strings = new String[10000];
    static byte[][] bytes = new byte[10000][];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random r = new Random();
        System.out.println("Generating strings/byte arrays");
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                s.append(r.nextInt(128) + 1);
            }
            strings[i] = s.toString();
            bytes[i] = strings[i].getBytes();
        }
        final String comparend = strings[r.nextInt(strings.length)];
        final byte[] byteComparend = comparend.getBytes();

        System.out.println("Comparing strings...");
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            comparend.equals(strings[i]);
        }
        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Comparing strings took %f s\n", (elapsed / 1000000000.0));

        System.out.println("Comparing byte arrays");
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            Arrays.equals(byteComparend, bytes[i]);
        }
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Comparing bytes took %f s\n", (elapsed / 1000000000.0));
    }
}
```

It seems String comparisons are orders of magnitude faster.

An example output on my machine is:

```
Generating strings/byte arrays
Comparing strings...
Comparing strings took 0.000010 s
Comparing byte arrays
Comparing bytes took 0.001339 s
```

Comment: Your approach is simplistic, so of course it gives these results. Strings in java are immutable objects, so they can undergo great optimizations. One of these optimizations is that their hashcode is precomputed. When you compare two strings, their hashcodes are first compared, and if they differ, the comparison of the actual characters is skipped, since it is known in advance that it will fail. In order to do a real test you would have to write a new class which encapsulates a byte array, behaves like an immutable object as string does, and contains the same types of optimizations.

Comment: Granted, strictly speaking, a byte-per-byte comparison between byte arrays (which is what the OP is asking) will not be faster than a string comparison. But then again that kind of usage would be naive.

Comment: @MikeNakis: this approach is what the OP is asking about. It's even faster than what the OP suggests doing, because it doesn't take into account the time it takes to transform Strings into bytes before comparing the byte arrays.

Comment: @MikeNakis: my approach is an attempt to answer the actual question asked with some simply produced evidence of why the approach is naive. It took five minutes to write a few lines of code that answered the question rather than a bunch of supposition.

Comment: @JB Nizet (and damianr) I acknowledged that in my comment starting with "Granted, ..." As for the transformation of strings into bytes before comparing the byte arrays, that would be insane, but that was not included in the question at the time I was writing my answer.